# Drawing Images twitching in processing

Tags: processing

In this sketch it draws a list of objects horizontally. Each object's x position is dependent on the object to its left. Also when the object is not on the screen it will not draw. However when i move, the objects twitch. I don't really know why, it could be that processing's load image takes a bit of time so there is a slight delay? I tested this with just drawing rectangles (rect()) and the problem doesn't happen.

[image: Here is a gif of what's happening]

The following is a code that draws images loaded from the internet with the same algorithm: (it might take a while for the sketch to load because it is retrieving the images from different websites) After running the sketch, use the left and right arrow keys to move left and right. Use the up and down arrows to change the movement speed.

```java
PImage backgroundImage;
PFont font;
int x = 0;
int xoffset = 0;
int deltax = 5;
float scale = 512/30;
float deltascale = 0.02;
ArrayList<Object> ObjectList;

class Object {
  String name;
  float diameter;
  String unit;
  String sprite;
  PImage img;
  int wid;
  int hei;
  int xpos;

  Object(String Oname, float Odiameter, String Ounit, String Oimg) {
    name = Oname;
    diameter = Odiameter;
    unit = Ounit;
    img = loadImage(Oimg);
    sprite = Oimg;
    //img = loadImage(Oimg);
    wid = img.width;
    hei = img.height;
  }
}

void setup() {
  size(1500, 800);
  frameRate(200);
  fill(255,255,255);
  textSize(32);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text("Images are loading (this may take a while)",700,400);
  ObjectList = new ArrayList();
  readObjects();
}

void addObject(String Aname, float Adiameter, String Aunit, String Aimg) {
  ObjectList.add(new Object(Aname, Adiameter, Aunit, Aimg));
}

void readObjects() {
  addObject("RED", 30, "m", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8f/1b/cc/8f1bcc72c81d1e9370597f7239ee476a.jpg");
  //addObject("ORANGE", 60, "m", "http://6iee.com/data/uploads/36/489075.jpg");
  addObject("YELLOW", 70, "m", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/aez1V.jpg");
  addObject("GREEN", 100, "m", "http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/mars.jpg");
  addObject("PURPLE", 105, "m", "http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/jupiter.png");
  addObject("PINK", 110, "m", "https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/4/4a/Alderaan.jpg");
  addObject("BROWN", 150, "m", "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/16/33/venus-151142_960_720.png");
  addObject("GRAY", 180, "m", "http://www.lpi.usra.edu/lpi_40th/images/1989/neptune.jpg");
  //addObject("WHITE", 200, "m", "http://www.clipartkid.com/images/19/log-in-sign-up-upload-clipart-Dpr48a-clipart.png");
  addObject("INDIGO", 300, "m", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Sun_in_February.jpg/155px-Sun_in_February.jpg");
  addObject("SKYBLUE", 301, "m", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Uranus_(Edited).jpg");
  addObject("BLUE", 1000, "m", "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/heman/images/3/36/Earth.jpg");
}




void draw() {

  fill(0,0,0);
  rect(0, 0, 1500, 800);

  int x = 0 + xoffset;
  for ( Object drawObject : ObjectList ) {   
    float dia = drawObject.diameter;

    if (x+drawObject.img.width >= 0 && x <= 1500) {


      //checks if image is too small to be drawn 
      int drawWidth = int(scale * dia);
      int drawHeight = int(drawWidth * drawObject.hei / drawObject.wid);
      if (drawWidth > 0 && drawHeight > 0) {
        drawObject.img.resize(drawWidth, drawHeight);
        image(drawObject.img, x, 400-(drawObject.img.height/2));
        //calculates font size relative to object's current size
        int textSize;
        //checks if the name or diameter is longer, then uses the longer one for calculation
        fill(255,255,255);
        if (drawObject.name.length() < str(drawObject.diameter).length()) {
          textSize = int(drawObject.img.width/str(drawObject.diameter).length());
        } else {
          textSize = int(drawObject.img.width/drawObject.name.length());
        }
        if (textSize > 0) {
          textSize(textSize);
          float texty = 418+(drawObject.img.height/2);
          if (texty < (418+(drawObject.img.height/2))) {
            texty = 418;
          }
          text(drawObject.name, x+(drawObject.img.width/2), texty);
          text(drawObject.diameter+drawObject.unit, x+(drawObject.img.width/2), texty+textSize);
        }
      }
      drawObject.xpos = x;
      x += (drawObject.img.width*0.08 + drawObject.img.width);
    }
    //display deltax
    textSize(32);
    text(str(deltax), 1450, 10);
    text(str(deltascale), 1450, 50);

    println(str(scale));
  }
}

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent event) {
  float e = event.getCount();
  if (e < 0) {
    scale *= (1 + deltascale);
  } else if (e > 0) {
    scale *= (1 - deltascale) ;
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      xoffset += deltax;
    } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      xoffset -= deltax;
    } else if (keyCode == UP) {
      deltax += 5;
    } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      deltax -= 5;
    }
  }
  if (key == 'r') {
    //reloadObjects();
  } else if (key == 'q') {
    deltascale += 0.02;
  } else if (key == 'a') {
    deltascale -= 0.02;
  }
  if (deltax < 0) {
    deltax = 0;
  } else if (deltascale < 0) {
    deltascale = 0;
  }
}
```

the following original code will NOT work because it uses images that only I have.

[The original code](https://pastebin.com/33pPBX08)

I hope someone can help me with this bug, or help me improve my algorithm.
EDIT: Code is now verifiable and presents the problems I'm having

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Like you said, the code you posted does not exhibit the problem, so it's going to be a little hard to help debug. Also, you really should try to format your code- the Processing editor will even do that for you. And one more thing: you really shouldn't use a class named `Object`, since there's already a Java class named `Object` which is confusing.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I have update the post and now contains a Verifiable example than exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I noticed that the image jumps whenever one of your images is about to go off the left edge of the screen.  It looks like you may be calculating the x position differently as each of your images goes offscreen.  Try getting rid of your `if (x+drawObject.img.width >= 0 && x <= 1500)` test (comment it out temporarily), but keep the code inside the `if`.

Few points:

- definitely don't create your own Object class (as Kevin Workman said)
- when you call `img.resize()` you are resampling the image data, which will lead to poor quality over time.  It would be better to just use the `width, height` parameters to the `image()` function (or use the `scale()` transformation function - but that may be more confusing).  Then use `drawWidth/Height` instead of `img.width/height` in the rest of your draw code.
- if you want to center an image, just use `imageMode(CENTER)` instead of doing the math yourself - especially since it looks like you're using a 'magic number' `400`
- try not to use raw numbers for your screen size - instead use the `width` & `height` globals -it'll make your life easier when you change the screen size.

Comment: Interestingly commenting out the if statement worked! I had that conditional before because I don't want processing to draw all the objects but only the ones that are on screen. In the future if I have a lot of objects, should I keep or still remove the if statement? I will definitely keep those points in mind :)

Comment: The part of the `if` statement that is important (in terms of keeping your drawing stable) is the part that changes your `x` value: `x += (drawObject.img.width*0.08 + drawObject.img.width);`  If you moved that one line to be outside your `if` you would avoid the twitching, and keep your optimizations.  In general, you want to do as little as possible inside a loop inside your draw function in order to keep your frame rate up.

Comment: adding the if statement back while having the x statement outside of it results in the same twitching, so I tried using the image(img,a,b,c,d) and it works smoothly! Thanks!